# Using data from a GET request to process a PUT request in same Python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, python-requests

I tried to ask a similar question before but I realize now that I was not specific enough. I am fairly new to Python but I am familiar with using the requests library to process GET requests. I am trying to set up a single script that will allow me to process several GET requests (using the request library) through a loop. I then need to use the information gathered from those GET requests in order to process several PUT requests (probably with a second loop) where I am changing the value of a particular field. For example, this is what I would receive back from one of my get requests:

```
{
"member": {
    "id": 12233444,
    "code": null,
    "code2": null,
    "code3": null,
    "state": "active",
    "cost_quarter": null,
    "master_id": 818667,
    "timeout_period": 2000,
    "enable_for_change": true,
    "is_prohibited": false,
    "site_id": 5544,
}}
```

I would then need to process a PUT request for each one of these GET requests to change the "timeout_period" to "5000". My PUT request would look like this for each member:

```
{
"member": {
    "id": 12233444,
    "code": null,
    "code2": null,
    "code3": null,
    "state": "active",
    "cost_quarter": null,
    "master_id": 818667,
    "timeout_period": 5000,
    "enable_for_change": true,
    "is_prohibited": false,
    "site_id": 5544,
}}
```

I am not really sure how I could accomplish this; is there a way to process several GET requests (through a loop), save that info somewhere, and then use it to process PUT requests (for each member) with the modified info?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So do you want to send a PUT request to a server while using second code snippet as request's JSON body?

Comment: No sorry, to be clear, I need to make several GET requests to an endpoint and then use the data obtained from those GET requests in order to process PUT requests for those same members. Reason being is, the "member" data may not always be the same so the structure has to be intact for each one of these members when I process the PUT requests. I only need to change a singe field value which in this example is the "timeout_period".

Comment: What I'm asking is 'how you process PUT requests'. It looks like JSON formatted data. If I understood correctly, first snippet(where `time_period` is 2000) is returned by a GET request. And you want to modify `time_period` value of that and then send a PUT request while using that data as JSON body of the request, right?

Comment: I would be using the same endpoint for both my GET requests and PUT requests. I am using GET to obtain MEMBER data. I want to use that same data (with a slight modification) for my PUT request.

Comment: Yes, I understood what you mean but still curious about how you send your data. JSON body? just plain text body?

Comment: @hallazzang: yes sorry that is correct, I should have been more specific. My GET request returns JSON data and my PUT request would use modified JSON data as well. In this case, it would be the "time_period" value that would be modified. Hopefully that makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

r = requests.get(...).json()
r['time_period'] = 5000

requests.put(..., json=r)
```

Use this method.

Comment: Ok great thanks. From here, if I wanted to process several "members", should I just set up a for loop?